# Type error: "Not a function" using "this" keyword in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have created the following function.

```
function showAllSelectOpts(select)
{
  selectLength = select.children().length;
  select.attr('size',selectLength);
  select.css('height','auto');
  select.focusout(function(){
      select.attr('size','1');
  });
}
```

When it is called directly on a select element like this `showAllSelectOpts(mySelect);` it works fine, but when called within another function, as below using the keyword "this", it returns the error. **Type error:  select.children not a function**

```
$('select').on('focus',function(){
  showAllSelectOpts(this);
})
```

Is this a scope issue or what, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: `this` in the event handler is the DOM element which triggered the `focus` event and not a jQuery object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an event handler, `this` is a reference to the DOM element, not a jQuery object. But your `showAllSelectOpts` expects its argument to be a jQuery object.

Either change the call to wrap the DOM element with `$()`:

```
showAllSelectOpts($(this));
```

...**or** update `showAllSelectOpts` to do so itself:

```
function showAllSelectOpts(select)
{
  select = $(select);                      // ***
  selectLength = select.children().length;
  select.attr('size',selectLength);
  select.css('height','auto');
  select.focusout(function(){
      select.attr('size','1');
  });
}
```

---

Side note: As A.Wolff [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40948738/type-error-not-a-function-using-this-keyword-in-a-function/40948768?noredirect=1#comment69107591_40948768), your function attaches a **new** `focusout` handler to the select **every time** it's called. You only want *one*.

I'd remove that part of the handler entirely, and replace it with a single `focusout`:

```
function showAllSelectOpts(select)
{
  var selectLength = select.children().length;
  select.attr('size',selectLength);
  select.css('height','auto');
}
$('select')
  .on('focus',function(){
    showAllSelectOpts($(this));
  })
  .on('focusout', function(){
    $(this).attr('size', '1');
  });
```

Also note that I added a `var` for `selectLength` in `showAllSelectOpts` (although actually, you could just remove the variable entirely); without one, the code is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*. Be sure to declare your variables.

Comment: *As a side note:* on each select `focus`, a new `focusout` event is bound. You should advice to use `one()` here :)

Comment: @A.Wolff: Good catch! I have to admit having read the first couple of lines of the function, I didn't read the rest of it!

Comment: @T.J. Crowder would `select.one('focusout'.function()...` replacing my original `select.focusout()...` work just as well, or is there a difference?

Comment: @skribe: It would, yes, but I wouldn't use it. Focus events are screwy, I couldn't absolutely guarantee you'd never get more than one `focus` with no intervening `focusout` (but maybe I'm paranoid). There's no particularly good reason for detaching/reattaching the handler every time. But if you want to, another option would be to use a namespaced event: `select.off("focusout.showall").on("focusout.showall", function() { ... });` **But**, yes, `one` is designed to remove the handler when the event fires.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery event listener callbacks set `this` as the HTMLElement that the event was fired on.

In your callback you are expecting a jQuery object, but you have the HTMLElement.

You can pass the HTMLElement to a jQuery constructor and pass it into the `showAllSelectOpts` function

```
$('select').on('focus',function(){
  showAllSelectOpts($(this));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var myselect  = $('select');

$('select').on('focus',function(){
  showAllSelectOpts(myselect);
})
```

**A better way could be:**

```
$('select').on('focus',function(event){
  showAllSelectOpts($(event.target));
})
```

**Why your code not working?**

```
$('select').on('focus',function(){
  //Here `this` is bound with the dom html element, not the $('select') object.
  showAllSelectOpts(this);
})
```

Comment: This won't work, because obviously I only want to run the function when any html "select"  element receives focus.  Besides that  `var myselect = $('select')` would include all select elements on the page.

Comment: *"A better way could be:"* Which has **exactly** the same problem the OP's code has: It's trying to use jQuery functions on a DOM element.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, you are right. I updated my code! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
$('select').on('focus',function()    { 
showAllSelectOpts($(this)); })
```

Answer (score 0):

These previous answers fix it. I'd just add here to create it as an extension since `$(this)` refers to a prototype of one method call.

```
$.fn.showAllSelectOpts=function() {
    $(this).on('focus',()=>{
        $(this)
            .css('height','auto')
            .attr('size',$(this).children().length)
            .focusout(()=>{
                $(this).attr('size','1');
            });
    });
};
$('select').showAllSelectOpts();
```